# I can't make my player move forward and backward! What is the problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to create a video game but I stuck in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/YiNCqmAF3Lc), in the tutorial it shows us to use input actions addon (What that does is it makes W-A-S-D or joystick type of keys easy to use) but even I watched the video after 3rd time I couldn't find the mistake! the problem is that I am not able to move my player forward or backward, I can only move it right and left. Please help I have tried so many things, like restarting the program or changing some code but it's not working can you help me to fix it?
Here is the first code to take the WASD commands from the addon script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   //Takes the wasd controls from addon
   InputWASD playerControls;

   public Vector2 movementInput;
   public float verticalInput;
   public float horizontalInput;

   private void OnEnable()
   {
       if (playerControls == null)
       {
           playerControls = new InputWASD();

           playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();
       }

       playerControls.Enable();
   }
   private void OnDisable()
   {
       playerControls.Disable();
   }

   public void HandleAllInputs()
   {
       HandleMovementInput();
       //TODO: HandleJumpInput
       //      HandleAttackInput
       //      HandleDashInput
       //      HandleAbilityInput
   }

   private void HandleMovementInput()
   {
       verticalInput = movementInput.y;
       horizontalInput = movementInput.x;
   }
}
```

Here is the second code to use keys in movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAct : MonoBehaviour
{
InputManager inputManager;
Vector3 moveDirection;
Transform cameraObject;
Rigidbody playersRB;

public float moveSpeed = 6f;
public float rotationSpeed = 15f;

private void Awake()
{
    inputManager = GetComponent<InputManager>();
    playersRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    cameraObject = Camera.main.transform;
}

public void HandleAllAction()
{
    HandleMovement();
    HandleRotation();
}

private void HandleMovement()
{
    moveDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputManager.verticalInput;
    moveDirection = moveDirection + cameraObject.right * inputManager.horizontalInput;
    moveDirection.Normalize();
    moveDirection.y = 0;
    moveDirection = moveDirection * moveSpeed;

    Vector2 movementVelocity = moveDirection;
    playersRB.velocity = movementVelocity;
}

private void HandleRotation()
{
    Vector3 targetDirection = Vector3.zero;

    targetDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputManager.verticalInput;
    targetDirection = targetDirection + cameraObject.right * inputManager.horizontalInput;
    targetDirection.Normalize();
    targetDirection.y = 0;

    if (targetDirection == Vector3.zero)
    {
        targetDirection = transform.forward;
    }

    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
    Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.rotation = playerRotation;
}
}
```

Here is the third and last code to use first 2 codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMain : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Calling scripts
    InputManager inputManager;
    PlayerAct playerAct;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputManager = GetComponent<InputManager>();
        playerAct = GetComponent<PlayerAct>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        inputManager.HandleAllInputs();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        playerAct.HandleAllAction();
    }
}
```

I did what the man told me (in the tutorial) but mine is not working!

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0):

sometime maybe the video is so old and unity is keep updating so some code maybe is not work anymore , maybe you should use the getinput system like float x= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")); and float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); this two is use characterController and let see how it work